# Background video is blank (black) on Android Chrome, works on PC

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html5-video

## Hello,

I'm trying to make a video as the background of a web page, and it seems to work on my PC, but not on my phone.
Up until now the video was not displayed, which is why I added a background to it, but now, after having messed around for a while, my phone *does* try to play the video, but it just ends up being blank (black) instead.
This resulted in a lack of both, background image and video.
But if I press and hold on the screen the option to *"Save video"* pops up, so I'm assuming the browser has no trouble realizing that there *should* be a video, it just fails to play.
Could the export settings be the issue?

---

#### HTML

```
<video id="bgvid" autoplay>
  <source src="media/video.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

#### CSS:

```
video#bgvid {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url(/img/background.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.25; }
```

#### Video

```
     File size:    6.39 MB (6,706,607 bytes)
      Duration:    1m 16s
    Dimensions:    
         Width:    1280px
        Height:    546px (arbitrary, I know)
 Constant kbps:    700

 Any further information about the file can be extracted and provided upon request.
```

---

I've tried commenting the "opacity: 0.25;" property just to see if that's what is causing all the trouble for Android, but no.
I'm actually writing everything in Jade and SASS in Brackets, these are the compiled (Prepros) codes.. mind you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend has suggested that I used this: http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/
which appears to be working on my desktop browser, but not on my phone.
So I guess that settles it: I shouldn't expect any video background to show on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you noticed that vodkabears Vide.js also has a background image called a "poster" as a fall back when the video formats are not supported by the browser

Check the docs here https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#readme where it says:

Prepare your video in several formats like '.webm', '.mp4' for cross browser compatibility, also add a poster with .jpg, .png or .gif extension:

I had the same issue - no video on chrome for android.
I didn't try an animated gif - that might work but not with the quality of video